# Passing variable types though mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, variables

Hello i am having a issue with htaccess mod_rewrite, maybe someone here could point in the the right direction.

my site has 1 main file [index.php] all the navigation is done by passing vars in the url string eg

```
index.php?page=about
```

this is working ok with my .htaccess [below]

```
domain.com/about
```

some of the pages have a second variable eg

```
index.php?page=event&eventID=42
```

this works too with the .htaccess below

```
domain.com/event/42
```

my problem is that I have other other pages that require vars too eg

```
index.php?page=news&newsID=4
domain.com/news/42

index.php?page=map&venueID=4
domain.com/map/42
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks in advance

.k

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/*([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=$1&eventType=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just do

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^event/([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=event&eventType=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=news&newsID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^map/([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=map&venueID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that was waht i was looking for, but I changes the var $2 to $1

^event/([^/\.]+)/*$ /index.php?page=event&eventType=$1

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^map/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=map&venueID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&$1ID=$2 [L]
```

Your `/map/…` URLs need a separate rule as the URL parameter is not `mapID` but `venueID`. But the rest should be covered by the third rule. But it would certainly be easier if you call the ID parameter just `id`.

Comment: thanks, was think that about the 'ID' that but the site is already code, just adding the .htacess now.

the last rule is great might just change venueID to mapID on the site