# PHP: get rid of '?p=' in url?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing varible types though mod-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318983/passing-varible-types-though-mod-rewrite)

howdy,
I'm using the get method on my current project. 
my links refer to `<a href='?p=". $path …` and i'm getting there values with `if(isset($_GET['p'])) …`

everytime i click a link the url in the adressbar changes to `mydomain.com/?p=files/path/subpath`

i wonder if i can somehow use mod_rewrite or anything else i order to get a prettier url. i'd love to get rid of the `"/?p=files/"` part in my url. it would be cool if the endresult would look like this:

`mydomain.com/path/subpath`

is that even possible?
regards matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using that type of URL, you are probably doing something wrong in your program.

For example, let's say you use an htpasswd file to store your web site users.  And I pass in `?p=../.htpasswd`.  Now I can break in as the user who has 'please' as their password.  Or I pass in `?p=/etc/passwd`, and get a list of the valid users on your system.

Yes, you can get rid of the `?p=` by using `mod_rewrite` ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html ).  But you should really make sure you know what you're doing and that arbitrary path specifications aren't possible.

Comment: +1 Security is everything these days!

Comment: shouldn't it be something like this?

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/*$ /?p=$1 [L]